# List Environment with Items On Blank lines

Tags: lists, line-breaking

How would one go about defining an environment that automatically places an itemize in front of whatever appears after each line break.

So

```
\begin{quicklist}
 foo

 bar

 quaz
 quiz

 zoom
\end{quicklist}
```

Would display results akin to

```
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\item bar
 \item quaz
       quiz
 \item zoom
\end{itemize}
```

Motivation is to make typing up simple notes and course handouts quick and painless even using an online latex editor like overleaf without all the fancy commands and multiline tools that sublime text and other programming editors make available.

Answer (score 1):

Just locally redefine `\par`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{quicklist}{\begin{itemize}\let\oldpar\par
\item\def\par{\oldpar\item}}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
Normal text
\begin{quicklist}
 foo

 bar

 quaz
 quiz

 zoom
\end{quicklist}
More normal text

Even more normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]